# I can't display detail_page with absolute_url?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

When I got this error I understood that I didn't learn URL -HTML- views-model relationship. First, let me show my codes.

This is my views.py:

```
def category_detail(request, category_name):
    links = Link.objects.filter(category__name=category_name)
    return render_to_response("category_detail.html", {"links":links}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

This is models.py:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_("Category"), max_length=255)
    user = models.ManyToManyField(User)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s %s" %(self.user, self.name)

    def admin_names(self):
        return ', '.join([a.username for a in self.user.all()])
    admin_names.short_description = "User Names"

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/category/%s" % self.name


class Link(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    posted_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    url = models.URLField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s %s %s" %(self.url, self.title, self.category)
```

This is HTML page:

```
<div id="profilemenu">
    index<p>
    {% for category in categories %}
        <p><a href="{% url 'category_detail' category.name %}">{{category.name }}</a>
    {% endfor %}
    <p>

</div>
```

and urls.py:

```
 url(r'^category/(?P<category_name>.*)', 'link.views.category_detail', name="category_detail"),
```

When I click a category name to open category_detail.html, the URL in browser is like :

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/category`/
```

I can't get categoryname. Please can you tell me my stupid mistake? :\ Thanks for time.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the namespace in your urls you would need to reference it without quotes in the template.

```
<p><a href="{% url category_detail category.name %}">{{category.name }}</a>
```

Note:  You'll want to ensure the namespace is fully qualified.  If you have embedded namespaces you should separate them with `:`.

```
<p><a href="{% url first_namespace:second_namespace:category_detail category.name %}">{{category.name }}</a>
```

Hopefully this solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should follow [`get_absolute_url` reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#get-absolute-url):

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
    return reverse('link.views.category_detail', args=[str(self.name)])
```

html

```
<a href="{{ category.get_absolute_url }}">{{ category.name }}</a>
```